# System hangs when I try to run a for loop (Java)

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner, freeze

I'm trying to set up a scanner that asks for item information using a loop. The system keeps hanging when I try to create an item object and I can't figure out why. Any ideas? Here's my code:

```
public class ItemAdd
{
// instance variables - replace the example below with your own
// private String itemName;
// private int cost;
// private String taxable;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Item
 */
public ItemAdd()
{
    System.out.println ("How many items do you have on your list?");
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    int count = scan.nextInt();
    if (count>0)

        for(;count>0; count--){
            System.out.println("What is the item name?");
            String itemName = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("How much does this item cost?");
            int cost = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Is this item taxable?");
            String taxable = scan.nextLine();

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing nextLine and any other next method, which doesn't work. Use `next()` instead of `nextLine()`. If you want spaces to be valid parts in item names, update the delimiter of the scanner immediately after creating it with `scanner.useDelimiter("\r?\n");`, then `next()` operates just like `nextLine()`, except not broken.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are learning object-oriented programming.

You have a class which will describe an Item. Each item will have three fields or properties - a name, cost and whether it is taxable.

The Main class includes the main method which is where Java starts executing your program. The main method calls the other code in the program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
  
public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

                Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println ("How many items do you have on your list?");
                int count = scan.nextInt();
                while (count>0){
                        // Create a new Item object and instantiate it
                        // This variable will be reused, meaning if you create 5
                        // objects, after the loop terminates there will only be
                        // one item variable. 
                        Item item = new Item();

                        // Display the item value (this calls the toString method)
                        System.out.println(item);
     
                        count--;
                }

        }
}


// This is the class which describes Item objects
class Item {

        // The properties of each item
        private String itemName;
        private int cost;
        private String taxable;

        // The constructor method which instantiates the object
        public Item() {

                // Get the values from the user and set the properties of the object
                Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("What is the item name? ");
                itemName = scan.next();
                System.out.print("How much does this item cost? ");
                cost = scan.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Is this item taxable? ");
                taxable = scan.next();
        }

        // Returns a string representation of the object
        public String toString() {
                return String.format("Name: %s%nCost: %d%nTaxable: %s%n", itemName, cost, taxable);
        }
}
```